# Exporting 2 button option issue in highchart

Tags: asp.net, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am using highchart, in that two button coming for exporting but I only want one

i tried the code below but it's not working..

```
                   exporting: {
                         buttons: { 
                            exportButton: {
                                enabled:true
                                          },
                              printButton: {
                                enabled:false
                              }
                          }
                     },
```

Please help? Or any suggestions?

Comment: Crete jsFiddle eaxample, please.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: null,
                    onclick: function() {
                        this.exportChart();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This will generate direct export button without any context menu

Check out this link

http://jsfiddle.net/HnGMZ/

Comment: have you check jsfiddle?

Comment: yes ..i check jsfiddle....in my website sometimes showing one button sometime showing two button

Comment: Humm.. You have to replace all your javascript code with this one, the clear browser cache and re check it, may be browser cache is the issue of sometime behaviour